# Adding Unicorn in production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I'm newer to programming and have an app up and running on Heroku which is nothing more than a sandbox for me to try to write working code. I just happened to come across the Heroku getting started guide (link below) that recommends using Unicorn when deploying Rails 4 apps.

Within this guide it states "Before pushing to Heroku you’ll want to test with the RACK_ENV set to production since this is the enviroment your Heroku app will run in." In development (local machine), I decided to try out what is suggested in the getting started guide and it works fine.

Now I would like to do this for my production environment. It isn't clear whether or not you would follow the identical instructions in the guide below substituting "production" for "development." I would greatly appreciate it if someone could confirm if that is the correct way for me to do this. If that is not the correct way, providing me some guidance on how to properly do this would also be appreciated.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Answer (score 0):

We've got unicorn working on Heroku like this:

```
#Gemfile
group :production do
    gem 'unicorn'
end

#Procfile
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

#config/unicorn.rb
# If you have a very small app you may be able to
# increase this, but in general 3 workers seems to
# work best
worker_processes 3

# Load your app into the master before forking
# workers for super-fast worker spawn times
preload_app true

# Immediately restart any workers that
# haven't responded within 30 seconds
timeout 30
```